# AutoLayout: Can I specify which constraint should break if needed and set a backup?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, autolayout, storyboard

Let's say I have an imageView that is set (1000 priority) to be 16px below the top of the screen. The width and height is currently set to >= 75 (1000 priority), and an aspect ratio that ensures it scales evenly (1000 priority).

If the keyboard slides up and makes it so that the imageView would need to be smaller than 75, I want to be able to specify that the h/w constraints should break, and should ideally default to some backup constraints of 0/0.

In other words, if the view ever wants to shrink the imageView less than 75x75, the view should get new constraints of 0/0 and disappear.

Right now when the keyboard slides up the bottom constraint of the imageView is breaking, not the w/h constraints.

Please help me understand what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define which constraints will be broken. Instead of that subscribe to notification when keyboard will appear and disable constraints which should not be used, or you can just set them to 0.